# Best practice to organise api links in Angular2

Tags: dependency-injection, configuration, angular

In angular2 app, we need to call a lot of 3rd party restful APIs. Any idea how to organise these APIs, so we can centralize the management of these APIs (maybe in a config file)?

For example, in angular2 tutorial

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data

imagine I have 20 services, every one of them will have a few functions inside to use http get, post accessing a bunch of 3rd party restful APIs. So I want to put all these API links in a centralize place, later if there is any change from 3rd party API providers, I can change without going into my services ts files?

**Updated**

config-values.ts

```
import {OpaqueToken} from 'angular2/core';
export const API_LOGIN = new OpaqueToken('API_LOGIN');
```

main.ts to bootstrap

...

```
import {API_LOGIN} from './app/shared/services/config-values';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(API_LOGIN, {useValue: 'http:bar.com/somepath'}),
  provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES], multi:true}),
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>' })
]);
```

In login.service.js which calls it

```
...
import {API_LOGIN} from 'config-values.ts';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  private loggedIn = false;
  constructor(@Inject(API_LOGIN) private apiUrl:string,private http:Http) {
    this.loggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit more what the question is about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a typescript file containing [OpaqueTokens](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OpaqueToken-class.html)s and pass them using DI

**config-values.ts**

```
export const API_FOO_URL = CONST_EXPR(new OpaqueToken('API Foo URL'));
export const API_BAR_URL = CONST_EXPR(new OpaqueToken('API Foo URL'));
...
export const API_URLS = CONST_EXPR([
  provide(API_FOO_URL, {useValue: 'http:foo.com/somepath'}), 
  provide(API_BAR_URL, {useValue: 'http:bar.com/somepath'}),
  ...
]);
```

**main.ts**

```
import {API_URLS} from 'config-values.ts';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [API_URLS, ...]);
```

**foo.service.ts**

```
import {API_FOO_URL} from 'config-values.ts';

@Injectable() 
export class FooService {
  constructor(@Inject(API_FOO_URL) private apiUrl:string) {}    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for

Comment: btw, what is CONST_EXPR function? or can use  export const API_FOO_URL: OpaqueToken = new OpaqueToken('API Foo URL')

Comment: I guess you can use that as well. AFAIK this is used in the Angular code base to make the code convertable to Dart. I don't use TS myself therefore I wasn't sure what vanilla TS syntax is for this.

Comment: interesting , not working , error : Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: Token API_LOGIN

Comment: my congig-values.ts is import {OpaqueToken} from 'angular2/core';

export const API_LOGIN = new OpaqueToken('API_LOGIN');

Comment: Ups, sorry, forgot to add the actual URL. I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks. but it seems @Inject  is not recognized - unresolved function or method inject()

Comment: You need to import `Inject` from `angular2/core`.

Comment: after added, a strange error angular2-polyfills.js?1461835289922:126 GET http://localhost:5555/node_modules/config-values.ts/package.json 404 (Not Found)

Comment: why it is going to access package.json? I update with the codes to the question

Comment: Looks like a configuration issue in your project. I guess I won't be able to help you with this (as mentioned I don't really use TS myself)